# getText from Edit Text when new line added

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, newline

Hey guys i am using edit text in my application.
Problem arises if user touches enter button on soft keyboard then the cursor drops down to 
new line and the user starts writting on new line.

For ex the user types :-

hey

guys

instead of hey guys

Then if i try getting the text from edit Text i am shown first hey and then next log debugger shows guys so the issue is that i am able to post some part of the message only to the server not the complete message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about replacing the newlines? or adding maxLines = 1 on the EditText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
yourEditBox.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                // intercept the return key
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

also it might help to set the `android:lines` attribute of your `EditText` to `1`.

Comment: Thanks Mannaz it did work but i was thinking that what if user wanted to enter a new line then? isnt there any other way so that the user can also format its data go to new line and i can also send the complete message in post

Comment: I't would be helpfull if you describe what you'r trying to do with the input of the textbox (maybe additional code sample).